# Add column name and select box in datatable table head

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have a datatable and I altered the table to have some column tableheads have select boxes on them to filter the data of the table.

My HTML

```
<table id="dataTableInventory" class="table table-striped table-bordered data-table-drafts" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="filterhead" style="display: none;">Item ID</th>
            <th class="filterhead">Main Category</th>
            <th class="filterhead">Sub Category</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Item Count</th>
            <th>In Stock</th>
            <th>Out Stock</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody id="table-body">
        <?php foreach($param_items as $item){?>
            <tr>
                <td class="id" style="display: none;"><?php echo $item->idx;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item->main_category;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item->sub_category;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item->item_name;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item->item_count;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item->in_stock;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item->out_stock;?></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="<?php echo base_url('dashboard/staff/inventory/view_item/'.$item->idx);?>" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-primary view-button"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a> <!-----------------------><a href="<?php echo base_url('dashboard/staff/inventory/in_item/'.$item->idx);?>" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-info in-button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a> <!-----------------------><a href="<?php echo base_url('dashboard/staff/inventory/out_item/'.$item->idx);?>" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-warning out-button"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a> <!-----------------------><button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-danger delete-button" data-url="<?php echo base_url('dashboard/staff/inventory/delete');?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

My JS

```
var table = $('#dataTableInventory').DataTable();
$(".filterhead").each( function ( i ) {
    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
        .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
        .on( 'change', function () {
           var term = $(this).val();
            table.column( i ).search(term, false, false ).draw();
        });
        table.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
    });
});
```

The problem is it doesnt just append the select box but it erases the tablehead names. It only shows the select box and the tablehead names are no longer there.

[image]

How do I do this to show the column tablehead name and also the select box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var table = $('#dataTableInventory').DataTable();
$(".filterhead").each( function ( i ) {
    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
        .appendTo( $(this) )
        .on( 'change', function () {
           var term = $(this).val();
            table.column( i ).search(term, false, false ).draw();
        });
        table.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
    });
});
```

everything is okey in your code except you are emptying the column you are appending to.
I just removed the  `.empty()`  method.

http://jsfiddle.net/hs2gbm3k/7/

Answer (score 1):

Can you do:

```
...
var select = $($(this).text() + '<select><option value=""></option></select>')
```

Or you can:

```
...
.appendTo( $(this) )
```

Instead of:

```
...
.appendTo( $(this).empty() )
```